# all my elements change location when trying to change only one element. css html

Tags: html, css

When I'm trying to put my H1 more down and to the left of the picture (like you can do in word) it stays on top of the page and shifts the whole navigation bar down etc. I tried it with `margin-top: down`; but that wouldn't work. also I want to let the underline appear with an fade when hovering over it in the nav bar but that wouldn't work either.

```css
body {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
}


/*Navigation Menu*/

ul {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
  /*Transition for animation*/
}

.active {
  display: block;
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/*On hover animation*/

ul li a:hover {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/*Images Home page*/

.IMG1TEXT {
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.IMG1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border: 5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--Navigation-->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#">Photo's</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Films</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Trips</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <h1 class="IMG1TEXT">Portofino, </h1>
  <img class="IMG1" src="img/Portofino1.png" height="350">
</body>
```

please help and this is some text because my post is mostly code so had to type something ig.

Comment: Can you make two versions of the snippet for the before and after? What image are you reffering to?

Comment: You should consider using grid (To divide your page in grid) or Flexbox to divide your page in "box". This way your page will be responsive and you'll be able to place your elements like you want without breaking the entire layout

Comment: Also, what is `margin-top: down`? Also, if you want to make a transition, you have to make a new css rule i.e. `a :hover {}` And then put in the styles you want to be applied when hovered

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are trying to get your `<h1>` tag down from the `nav` tab and to place on left of the image.

Changes made:

1. `nav` tab is styled.
2. `h1` and the `img` tag are put into a single `div` .

```css
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
} 

/*navigation menu*/
nav{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background-color: red;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
nav ul{
    display:flex;
    gap:50px
}
nav ul li{
    list-style:none;
}
nav ul li a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color:whitesmoke;
}

/*content*/

h1{
    margin-top:50px; /*your desired value*/
}

div{
    margin-top:3%;
    display:flex;
}
```

```html
<!--Navigation-->
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Photo's</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Films</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Trips</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">
      <h1 class="IMG1TEXT">Portofino, </h1>
      <img class="IMG1" src="img/Portofino1.png" height="350">
</div>
```

Following these steps you will acheive your target.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can manage your page layout using Flexbox.

[Here is documentation on flexbox](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

```css
body {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
}

.master-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}


/*Navigation Menu*/

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 35%;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 1s ease-out;
  /*Transition for animation*/
}

.active {
  color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: underline;
}


/*On hover animation*/

ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}


/*Images Home page*/

.IMG1TEXT {
  margin-top: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.IMG1 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 50px;
  border: 5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--Navigation-->
  <div class="master-container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#">Photo's</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Films</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Trips</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="main-container">
      <h1 class="IMG1TEXT">Portofino, </h1>
      <img class="IMG1" src="img/Portofino1.png" height="350">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```